# Recapture keyboard focus in Kivy after clicking out of a `TextInput` object

Tags: python, textbox, focus, kivy, keyboard-events

The following code creates a [Kivy](https://kivy.org/) app with a single screen, `MainScreen`, displaying a `Label` and `TextInput` object.

If you give some keyboard input when the app first loads, it prints in the console with information about which key was pressed. However, if you then click in the `TextInput` object the keyboard refocuses so you can type in the `TextInput` object. However, once you click back out of the `TextInput` object, e.g. on the label or background, and press more keys, the same console printing operation doesn't execute; it seems that the keyboard doesn't 'defocus' from the `TextInput` object.

How do I recapture keyboard focus after clicking out of a `TextInput` object?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

kv = '''ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Label"
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        TextInput
            input_filter: 'float'
            font_size: 20
            hint_text: "Input Text"
            size_hint: 0.2,0.1'''

class MainScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print('INFO: The key', keycode, 'has been pressed')

        return True # return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by the system.

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: A user on the Kivy IRC also provided this answer: https://pastebin.com/nYs4fHvT, which creates a button to re-focus the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the `on_touch_down` event and reconfigure the keyboard if you press a section that does not contain a `TextInput`:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.config_keyboard()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.isTextInput = False

        def filter(widget):
            for child in widget.children:
                filter(child)
            if isinstance(widget, TextInput) and widget.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                self.isTextInput = True
                widget.on_touch_down(touch)

        filter(self)

        if not self.isTextInput and self._keyboard is None:
            self.config_keyboard()

    def config_keyboard(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print('INFO: The key', keycode, 'has been pressed')

        return True # return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by the system.
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems a bit verbose, but it works well.